# 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: tile_movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip, flash-cs4

I'm following the book "Flash Game Development By Example", and I'm currently on the Chapter Two, on the Minesweeper game.
The problem I'm having is after I start inputting the code to make the tile displaying and I got the following errors:
`1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: tile_movieclip.` and `1180: Call to a possibly undefined method tile_movieclip.`.
The lines where they've appeared are, respectively:

`private var tile:tile_movieclip;`

and

`tile = new tile_movieclip();`

I have no clue about why it isn't working. The book doesn't mentions anything about the error, and I've already tried copy/pasting the code from the book, but it haven't worked either. I'm currently using Adobe Flash CS4.

The current source code is here: http://pastebin.com/spUzPGBx. It might have other errors, since I was still debugging it when I found this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for that code to work, you need 1 of 2 possible things :

1 - A class named tile_movieclip

2 - A library symbol that is named tile_movieclip and has linkage set on it's properties panel, which will automatically create a class named tile_movieclip when compiled.

I am going to guess that the book you are using has a .fla file that goes along with that example.

**UPDATE - I just downloaded the .pdf of that book and on page 22 it describes creating this symbol in your library and setting linkage.**

So.... I think we can consider this mystery solved.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but thanks! Although I'm on the second game, Minesweeper, your solution worked. Page 56 says that I should name the symbol tile_movieclip, and make it an exportable actionscript with that same name. Changed it and now it works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

That means the flash thinks the class `tile_movieclip` does not exist. If it does indeed exist then it means flash doesn't know how to access it.

There are many possible reasons why this happens depending on how your project is structured. If you are trying to access an external library, a library item, some class in your project, etc.

Please specify in your question where you think the class `tile_movieclip` is located and I'll be able to provide a more specific answer.

As a side note, in AS3 (and probably all programming languages) it is a standard to name classes with an upper case letter, so it's easier to distinguish between vars and classes. In AS3 in particular `sprite` is a var, and `Sprite` is a class. AS3 is a case sensitive language.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I'm not using any external libraries or anything, and all the code is on my Main.as file (I know that this is a bad practice, but it's the way the book do it). The book does not mention the needing of any custom library or anything like that. I thought it was a built-in flash function. Do I need to import anything for it to work? I've already tried `import flash.display.Movieclip`, but it didn't made any difference. 

Also, thanks for the tip on the case sensitive.

Comment: Well, then your project is missing something. `var tile:tile_movieclip;` means you are creating a var of type `tile_movieclip` which is a class. If you don't have that class in your project, it will never work. Are you sure this class is not created in a previous chapter of the book?

Comment: tile_movieclip should be spelled "Tile_movieclip" (as the classes should be mentioned by a caps) and should extend MovieClip. private var tile:Tile_movieclip / private var tile:MovieClip. Be sure that the path / package are correct, imported in the specified class, and well placed as it should in the project. Is this helpfull?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I had forgotten to name my movieclip "tile_movieclip" and export it as an AS3 class.